# select forms by clicking on the picture?

Tags: jquery, image, select, click

Hello I have is the code to change the language

```
Language: 
<form action="" name="lngs" method="post">
  <select name="lng" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <option value="pl"{PL_SEL}>Polski</option>
    <option value="en"{EN_SEL}>English</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

how to modify it so that you can change the language by clicking on the picture, eg:

```
<img src = "pl.png"> 
<img src = "en.png">
```

after clicking on the images to change the language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the language from the image and make that the selected item in the dropdown, then post the form:

```
$('img').click(function(){
  $('form[name=lngs] select[name=lng]').val($(this).attr('src').replace('.png', ''));
  $('form[name=lngs]').submit();
});
```